# Creating C# client app for web service created also with C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created simple web service that works fine if I test with tools. Now I would like to write C# client application for this purpose. What is the best way to do that.

I'm trying to add service reference with web service addres. I expect that web service somehow give WSDL information to client side. But this not happens:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:11332/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:11332/'.
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 787 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

What is the best way to make client application for web service when both is created with C#?

UPD:

Now both - client and service are in the same solution. In case I try to add reference when web service is not running by selecting "Services in solution" it finds nothing.

Comment: What happens if you add the web service as a reference?

Comment: If both your web service and your client app projects are inside the same Visual Studio solution, you can ask Visual Studio to look for web services inside the solution when adding the service reference.

Comment: When I add web service reference I have error described in question body

Comment: Now both - client and service are in the same solution. In case I try to add reference when web service is not running by selecting "Services in solution" it finds nothing

Comment: try ?wsdl instead of $metadata maybe

Comment: it adds $metadata automatically to address I typed in

Comment: Are you sure you created a WCF (or asmx) web service? I don't think we can help you without seeing some code. It sound more like you created a ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: looks like I found problem. Since it is REST service I suppose it is not possible to create client by adding reference in such way.